# generate a base-64 encoded sha-256 password hash with openssl on the Windows command line

Tags: windows, shell, base64, sha256

I'm trying to password encrypt a text string with SHA-256 HMAC and then encode in base64 using openssl in a Windows command line. Ideally I'd like to have that info output in a text file.

As a first step, I tried using known text strings like "Message" and "secret" in the command line without output to file. When I run

`"echo -n "Message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "secret" -binary | openssl base64"`

in Windows command, the answer is "vU1EEiVOomLI5ebeFWNdnBKNtmvaWxY0RP7r3tkBBeQ=". However, the correct output string should be "qnR8UCqJggD55PohusaBNviGoOJ67HC6Btry4qXLVZc=".

I tried many different combinations and I'm at loss what I'm doing wrong. After that, I'll have to figure out how to output to a file.

Comment: Just curious, how did you determine what the correct output string would be; other program? Online?